# Graphics artifacts appear here in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, 2d

In my custom JPanel appears graphic artifacts. I dont know why, because I have used super.paintComponent() in all of my custom paintings.

1. **Here is how it looks on create.**

[image: on create]


 2. **And here is how it looks when I click on upgrades button.**

[image: on click]

## And here is the code.

#### Menu

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class Menu {

    static JFrame frame;
    public static double scale = 1.5;
    private static int WIDTH = 300, HEIGHT = 400;
    public static Font fontTerminal;
    private JPanel menuPanel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Menu window = new Menu();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public Menu() throws IOException {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    private void initialize() throws IOException {
        fontTerminal = new Font("Consolas", 1, 1);
        try {
            fontTerminal = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("res/terminal.ttf"));
        } catch (FontFormatException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }  


        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        menuPanel = new BackgroundPanel();
        menuPanel.setLayout(null);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_menuPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_menuPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_menuPanel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_menuPanel.gridy = 0;
        frame.getContentPane().add(menuPanel, gbc_menuPanel);

        GameButton newgameButton = new GameButton();
        int ngButtWidth = 194, ngButtHeight = 71; 
        newgameButton.setBounds((frame.getWidth()/2) - (ngButtWidth/2), (frame.getHeight()/2) - (ngButtHeight/2), ngButtWidth, ngButtHeight);
        newgameButton.setBackground( new Color(0,0,0,0));
        menuPanel.add(newgameButton);
        newgameButton.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JLabel newgameLbl = new GLabel("New Game", newgameButton, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        newgameLbl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                GameWindow gp = new GameWindow();
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        newgameLbl.setFont(fontTerminal.deriveFont(19f));
        newgameLbl.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
        newgameButton.add(newgameLbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        GameButton creditsButton = new GameButton();
        creditsButton.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        creditsButton.setBounds(56, 262, 194, 71);
        menuPanel.add(creditsButton);
        creditsButton.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JLabel creditsLabel = new GLabel("Credits", creditsButton, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        creditsLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                Credits credits = new Credits();
                credits.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        creditsLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        creditsLabel.setFont(null);
        creditsLabel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        creditsLabel.setFont(fontTerminal.deriveFont(19f));
        creditsButton.add(creditsLabel);
    }
}
```

#### GameWindow

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;









import javax.swing.UIManager.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Insets;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JTable;


public class GameWindow {

    private JFrame frame;
    private Font fontTerminal;
    private JPanel workerPanel1;
    private GProgressbar Bar1;
    private GameButton upgradeWorker1;
    private JLabel upgradeWorker1_1;
    private JPanel workerPanel2;
    private GProgressbar Bar2;
    private GameButton upgradeWorker2;
    private JPanel workerPanel3;
    private GProgressbar Bar3;
    private GameButton upgradeWorker3;
    private JPanel workerPanel4;
    private GProgressbar Bar4;
    private GameButton upgradeWorker4;
    private JPanel upgradesPanel;
    private JLabel upgradeWorker2_1;
    private JLabel upgradeWorker3_1;
    private JLabel upgradeWorker4_1;
    private JPanel specialPanel;
    private JPanel upgradesButton;
    private JTable table, table2;

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public GameWindow() {
        initialize();
        this.frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
        }
        fontTerminal = Menu.fontTerminal;



        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 306, 430);
        //frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() { 
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame.dispose();
                Menu.frame.setVisible(true);
            }}); 

        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        gamePanel.setLayout(null);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_menuPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_menuPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_menuPanel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_menuPanel.gridy = 0;
        frame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel, gbc_menuPanel);

                                upgradesPanel = new JPanel();
                                upgradesPanel.setBounds(23, 221, 253, 174);
                                upgradesPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
                                gamePanel.add(upgradesPanel);

                                workerPanel1 = new JPanel();
                                workerPanel1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
                                GridBagLayout gbl_workerPanel1 = new GridBagLayout();
                                gbl_workerPanel1.columnWidths = new int[]{119, 118, 0};
                                gbl_workerPanel1.rowHeights = new int[]{36, 0};
                                gbl_workerPanel1.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
                                gbl_workerPanel1.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
                                workerPanel1.setLayout(gbl_workerPanel1);

                                        Bar1 = new GProgressbar();
                                        Bar1.setStringPainted(true);
                                        GridBagConstraints gbc_Bar1 = new GridBagConstraints();
                                        gbc_Bar1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                                        gbc_Bar1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
                                        gbc_Bar1.gridx = 0;
                                        gbc_Bar1.gridy = 0;
                                        workerPanel1.add(Bar1, gbc_Bar1);

                                        upgradeWorker1 = new GameButton();
                                        GridBagConstraints gbc_upgradeWorker1 = new GridBagConstraints();
                                        gbc_upgradeWorker1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                                        gbc_upgradeWorker1.gridx = 1;
                                        gbc_upgradeWorker1.gridy = 0;
                                        workerPanel1.add(upgradeWorker1, gbc_upgradeWorker1);

                                        upgradeWorker1_1 = new GLabel("Upgrade", upgradeWorker1, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                                        upgradeWorker1_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                                                //upgrade worker 1
                                            }
                                        });
                                        upgradeWorker1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
                                        upgradeWorker1_1.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
                                        upgradeWorker1.add(upgradeWorker1_1);

                                workerPanel2 = new JPanel();
                                workerPanel2.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                                GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
                                gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{119, 118, 0};
                                gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{36, 0};
                                gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
                                gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
                                workerPanel2.setLayout(gbl_panel);


                                Bar2 = new GProgressbar();
                                Bar2.setStringPainted(true);
                                GridBagConstraints gbc_Bar2 = new GridBagConstraints();
                                gbc_Bar2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                                gbc_Bar2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
                                gbc_Bar2.gridx = 0;
                                gbc_Bar2.gridy = 0;
                                workerPanel2.add(Bar2, gbc_Bar2);

                                upgradeWorker2 = new GameButton();
                                GridBagConstraints gbc_upgradeWorker2 = new GridBagConstraints();
                                gbc_upgradeWorker2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                                gbc_upgradeWorker2.gridx = 1;
                                gbc_upgradeWorker2.gridy = 0;
                                workerPanel2.add(upgradeWorker2, gbc_upgradeWorker2);
                                upgradeWorker2.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

                                upgradeWorker2_1 = new GLabel("Upgrade", upgradeWorker2, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                                upgradeWorker2_1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                                upgradeWorker2_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                                        //upgrade worker 2
                                    }
                                });
                                upgradeWorker2.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
                                upgradeWorker2_1.setFont(fontTerminal.deriveFont(15f));
                                upgradeWorker2.add(upgradeWorker2_1);

                                workerPanel3 = new JPanel();
                                workerPanel3.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                                GridBagLayout gbl_workerPanel3 = new GridBagLayout();
                                gbl_workerPanel3.columnWidths = new int[]{119, 118, 0};
                                gbl_workerPanel3.rowHeights = new int[]{36, 0};
                                gbl_workerPanel3.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
                                gbl_workerPanel3.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
                                workerPanel3.setLayout(gbl_workerPanel3);

                                Bar3 = new GProgressbar();
                                Bar3.setStringPainted(true);
                                GridBagConstraints gbc_Bar3 = new GridBagConstraints();
                                gbc_Bar3.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                                gbc_Bar3.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
                                gbc_Bar3.gridx = 0;
                                gbc_Bar3.gridy = 0;
                                workerPanel3.add(Bar3, gbc_Bar3);

                                upgradeWorker3 = new GameButton();
                                GridBagConstraints gbc_upgradeWorker3 = new GridBagConstraints();
                                gbc_upgradeWorker3.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                                gbc_upgradeWorker3.gridx = 1;
                                gbc_upgradeWorker3.gridy = 0;
                                workerPanel3.add(upgradeWorker3, gbc_upgradeWorker3);
                                upgradeWorker3.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

                                upgradeWorker3_1 = new GLabel("Upgrade", upgradeWorker3, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                                upgradeWorker3.add(upgradeWorker3_1);

                                workerPanel4 = new JPanel();
                                workerPanel4.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                                GridBagLayout gbl_workerPanel4 = new GridBagLayout();
                                gbl_workerPanel4.columnWidths = new int[]{119, 118, 0};
                                gbl_workerPanel4.rowHeights = new int[]{36, 0};
                                gbl_workerPanel4.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
                                gbl_workerPanel4.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
                                workerPanel4.setLayout(gbl_workerPanel4);

                                Bar4 = new GProgressbar();
                                Bar4.setStringPainted(true);
                                GridBagConstraints gbc_Bar4 = new GridBagConstraints();
                                gbc_Bar4.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                                gbc_Bar4.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
                                gbc_Bar4.gridx = 0;
                                gbc_Bar4.gridy = 0;
                                workerPanel4.add(Bar4, gbc_Bar4);

                                upgradeWorker4 = new GameButton();
                                GridBagConstraints gbc_upgradeWorker4 = new GridBagConstraints();
                                gbc_upgradeWorker4.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                                gbc_upgradeWorker4.gridx = 1;
                                gbc_upgradeWorker4.gridy = 0;
                                workerPanel4.add(upgradeWorker4, gbc_upgradeWorker4);
                                upgradeWorker4.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

                                upgradeWorker4_1 = new GLabel("Upgrade", upgradeWorker4, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                                upgradeWorker4.add(upgradeWorker4_1);


                                GroupLayout gl_upgradesPanel = new GroupLayout(upgradesPanel);
                                gl_upgradesPanel.setHorizontalGroup(
                                    gl_upgradesPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(gl_upgradesPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addContainerGap()
                                            .addGroup(gl_upgradesPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addComponent(workerPanel1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 238, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(workerPanel2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 238, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(workerPanel3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 238, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(workerPanel4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 238, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                            .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                );
                                gl_upgradesPanel.setVerticalGroup(
                                    gl_upgradesPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(gl_upgradesPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addContainerGap()
                                            .addComponent(workerPanel1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                            .addComponent(workerPanel2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                            .addComponent(workerPanel3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                            .addComponent(workerPanel4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                );
                                upgradesPanel.setLayout(gl_upgradesPanel);

                                specialPanel = new JPanel();
                                specialPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0.2f));
                                specialPanel.setBounds(6, 6, 288, 203);
                                gamePanel.add(specialPanel);
                                specialPanel.setLayout(null);

                                String[] columnNames = {"Upgrades", ""};
                                Object[][] data =
                                {
                                    {"Vozík +2",    "2000$"},
                                    {"Kalhoty +3",  "15000$"},
                                    {"Šperháky +4", "50000$"},
                                    {"Auto *2",     "200000$"},
                                };

                                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames){
                                     @Override
                                     public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                                           if(column != 1) return false;
                                           else return true;
                                        }
                                };

                                table = new JTable( model );

                                Action upgradeMultiplier = new AbstractAction()
                                {
                                    int count = 0;
                                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                                    {
                                        /*
                                         * 
                                        JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
                                        int modelRow = Integer.valueOf( e.getActionCommand() );                
                                        String sPrice = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 1);
                                        int price = Integer.parseInt(sPrice.substring(0,sPrice.length()-1));    
                                        String sMultip = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 0);
                                        if(sMultip.lastIndexOf("*") != -1) {
                                            int multip = Integer.parseInt(sMultip.substring(sMultip.lastIndexOf("*")+1,sMultip.length()));
                                            if(player.money.getMoney() >= price) {
                                                player.money.deduct(price);
                                                worker.multiplyMultiplier(multip);
                                                ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(modelRow);  
                                            }
                                        } else if(sMultip.lastIndexOf("+") != -1) {
                                            int multip = Integer.parseInt(sMultip.substring(sMultip.lastIndexOf("+")+1,sMultip.length()));
                                            if(player.money.getMoney() >= price) {
                                                player.money.deduct(price);
                                                worker.plusMultiplier(multip);
                                                ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(modelRow);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        progressBar1.setString(worker.getProfit()+"$");
                                        lblMultiplier.setText(worker.multiplier+"x");
                                        *
                                        */
                                    }
                                };

                                ButtonColumn buttonColumn = new ButtonColumn(table, upgradeMultiplier , 1);
                                buttonColumn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);

                                table.setBounds(8, 55, 272, 142);
                                specialPanel.add(table);


                                String[] columnNames2 = {"Upgrades", ""};
                                Object[][] data2 =
                                {
                                    {"Special +1",  "2000$"},
                                    {"Special +3",  "15000$"},
                                    {"Special +4", "50000$"},
                                    {"SPecial *2",  "200000$"},
                                };

                                DefaultTableModel model2 = new DefaultTableModel(data2, columnNames2){
                                     @Override
                                     public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                                           if(column != 1) return false;
                                           else return true;
                                        }
                                };

                                table2 = new JTable( model2 );

                                Action specialUpgrade = new AbstractAction()
                                {
                                    int count = 0;
                                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                                    {
                                        /*
                                         * 
                                        JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
                                        int modelRow = Integer.valueOf( e.getActionCommand() );                
                                        String sPrice = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 1);
                                        int price = Integer.parseInt(sPrice.substring(0,sPrice.length()-1));    
                                        String sMultip = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 0);
                                        if(sMultip.lastIndexOf("*") != -1) {
                                            int multip = Integer.parseInt(sMultip.substring(sMultip.lastIndexOf("*")+1,sMultip.length()));
                                            if(player.money.getMoney() >= price) {
                                                player.money.deduct(price);
                                                worker.multiplyMultiplier(multip);
                                                ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(modelRow);  
                                            }
                                        } else if(sMultip.lastIndexOf("+") != -1) {
                                            int multip = Integer.parseInt(sMultip.substring(sMultip.lastIndexOf("+")+1,sMultip.length()));
                                            if(player.money.getMoney() >= price) {
                                                player.money.deduct(price);
                                                worker.plusMultiplier(multip);
                                                ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(modelRow);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        progressBar1.setString(worker.getProfit()+"$");
                                        lblMultiplier.setText(worker.multiplier+"x");
                                        *
                                        */
                                    }
                                };

                                ButtonColumn buttonColumn2 = new ButtonColumn(table, specialUpgrade , 1);
                                buttonColumn2.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);

                                table2.setBounds(8, 55, 272, 142);
                                table2.setVisible(false);
                                specialPanel.add(table2);

                                upgradesButton = new GameButton();
                                upgradesButton.setBounds(8, 6, 121, 43);
                                specialPanel.add(upgradesButton);
                                upgradesButton.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
                                upgradesButton.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

                                GLabel label4 = new GLabel("Upgrades", (GameButton) upgradesButton, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                                label4.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                                        table.setVisible(true);
                                        table2.setVisible(false);
                                    }
                                });
                                upgradesButton.add(label4);

                                JPanel specialsButton = new GameButton();
                                specialsButton.setBounds(159, 6, 121, 43);
                                specialPanel.add(specialsButton);
                                specialsButton.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
                                specialsButton.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

                                GLabel lblSpecials = new GLabel("Specials", (GameButton) specialsButton, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                                lblSpecials.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                                        table.setVisible(false);
                                        table2.setVisible(true);
                                    }
                                });
                                specialsButton.add(lblSpecials);
    }
}
```

#### GamePanel extends JPanel

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        try {
            final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("./res/gameBackground.jpg"));
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 300, 400, this);   
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}


    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class GProgressbar extends JProgressBar {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

#### GameButton extends JPanel

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameButton extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    boolean entered = false;
    boolean pressed = false;
    GameButton that = this;

    public GameButton() {
        this.setOpaque(true);

        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                that.entered = true;
                that.repaint();
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                that.entered = false;
                that.repaint();
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            }
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                that.pressed = true;
                that.repaint();
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                that.pressed = false;
                that.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        if(!entered) {
            try {
                final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("./res/button.gif"));
                g.drawImage( image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if(pressed){
            try {
                final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("./res/buttonpressed.gif"));
                g.drawImage( image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        } else {
            try {
                final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("./res/buttonactive.gif"));
                g.drawImage( image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### GLabel extends JLabel

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class GLabel extends JLabel{

    GameButton that;


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public GLabel(String s, GameButton that, int center) {
        this.setText(s);
        this.that = that;
        this.setHorizontalAlignment(center);

        setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        setFont(Menu.fontTerminal.deriveFont(15f));
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));

        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                that.entered = true;
                that.repaint();
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                that.entered = false;
                that.repaint();
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                that.pressed = true;
                that.repaint();
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                that.pressed = false;
                that.repaint();
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Comment: That project compiles and runs if you copy that code into compiler.

Comment: But it's far from minimal and not an example. I'm sure you can reproduce the problem with no more than 80 lines of code. You can take your chances and wait to see if someone wants to read all of that extra code you posted and do the hard work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make the background fully transparent.

Then all you need is:

```
component.setOpaque( false );
```

If you need partial transparency of the background then you will get artifacts as you will be breaking the painting contract with Swing components and the opaque property. Check out 
[Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information and solutions to this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I am used to write invisible color in that format because of css. Your answer helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you set a fully transparent JPanel for '`workerPanel1`'.
As such, the background is showing behind the JPanel.

Instead of:

```
workerPanel1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0))
```

use:
`workerPanel1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0))`
(which is the same as: `new Color(0,0,0,255)`)

**Edit:**
If you wish to keep a transparent panel, you can do so with JPanel#setOpaque(false).
When opaque is false, the panel does not draw its background at all and you will have to keep in mind whatever is displayed behind that panel.
Currently, you have two buttons showing behind it, so you might setVisible(false) them or remove them while this panel is active.

Comment: Thanx for an answer. I wanted to use fully transparent background. I know that new Color(r, g, b, opacity) sets the opacity and I want to make the background fully transparent.

Comment: @Krystofee Swing only knows how paint fully transparent or fully opaque components, you can't use alpha based colors to achive this